# Docker deploy in smart contract

Tags: cloud, blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts

Taking a database server in a Docker container that could deployed by a smart contract on your local machine.

How to do this?

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

In Ethereum, using only a smart contract, you cannot work directly with the host's software environment. A smart contract can work exclusively with the data of the blockchain itself.

If you want to implement the required deployment procedure, you must additionally create an Oracle service that will receive information from a smart contract and perform the required actions in the context of the host operating system. At the same time, you need to think about how you will redo the docker image, since its direct transfer through the blockchain is unrealistic. To do this, you can use, for example, ipfs, cloud storage, web repositories, and so on.

Comment: My question how can I deploy docker container by using smart contracts